# Relation between continuous and discrete limsup and liminf

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I know that, given a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ we have that:
$$ \lim _{x \to x_0} f(x)=\lambda \iff \lim _{n \to +\infty} f(x_n)=\lambda $$ for every sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that  $x_n \to x_0$.

I was wondering if we can say the same thing for $\liminf$ and $\limsup$, considering the two different definitions:
$$\limsup_{n \to +\infty} f(x_n)=\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left( \sup _{k \ge n} f(x_k)\right), \quad \limsup _{x \to x_0} f(x)=\lim _{r \to 0^+} \left( \sup _{x \in B(x_0,r)} f(x) \right)$$
And analogous definition for the $\liminf$. In other words, I was wondering if it's true that:
$$\limsup _{x \to x_0} f(x)=\lambda \iff \limsup _{n \to +\infty} f(x_n)=\lambda$$ for every sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_n \to x_0$
And same for the $\liminf$.

Edit: because of the answer by Goonfiend, which provided an example of $$\liminf _{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) < \liminf _{n \rightarrow +\infty} f(x_n)$$
I tried to prove that
$$\liminf _{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) \le \liminf _{n \rightarrow +\infty} f(x_n) \ , \ \limsup _{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) \ge \limsup _{n \rightarrow +\infty} f(x_n) $$
for every sequence $x_n \rightarrow x_0$.

Proof: because of the above characterization of limits, we have that
$$\quad \limsup _{x \to x_0} f(x)=\lim _{r \to 0^+} \left( \sup _{x \in B(x_0,r)} f(x) \right)=\lim _{n\rightarrow +\infty}\left( \sup _{x \in B(x_0,r_n)} f(x) \right)= \inf _{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left( \sup _{x \in B(x_0,r_n)} f(x) \right)$$
Where $(r_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an arbitrary decreasing infinitesimal sequence ($r_n \searrow 0$). Then we can choose $r_n$ such that $x_k \in B(x_0,r_n)$ for every $k \ge n$. This means that
$\{x_k \mid k \ge n\} \subseteq B(x_0,r_n)$, and so we have that
$$\sup _{k \ge n} f(x_k) \le \sup _{x \in B(x_0,r_n)} f(x) \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left( \sup _{k \ge n} f(x_k)\right) \le \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left( \sup _{x \in B(x_0,r_n)} f(x)\right)$$
And this means, by definition, that
$$\limsup _{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) \ge \limsup _{n \rightarrow +\infty} f(x_n)$$

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: You are expected to show your own efforts on the problem.

Comment: It turns out that $\lim\limits _{x \to x_0} f(x)$ is the maximum of the extended real numbers $\limsup \limits_{n \to +\infty} f(x_n)$ for all possible sequences $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x_0.$ The reason for saying it's the maximum rather than the least upper bound is that one can show that the least upper bound is actually achieved in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not true. Consider $f(x)=1_\mathbb{Q}$. Then $$\liminf_{x\to 0}f(x)=0\neq 1= \liminf_{n\to \infty} f(1/n).$$
It is false for lim sup too for similar reasons.